# How to add speech.dll in c# setup?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll, installation

After creating a speech app, I am about to publish it. I noticed that "one click publish" is not working since it do not include te speech.dll in setup.

How can I add these dlls into the setup?

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

1. From the Project menu, select Add and click File.
2. Find the folder that contains MyApplication.exe and MyLibrary.DLL and select them both.
3. In the File System window, right-click on Application Folder, point to Add and click Create to create a new folder. Call it MyLibrary.
4. Click on Application Folder again, select MyLibrary.DLL and drag it to the MyLibrary folder.In Solution Explorer, under your project in Detect Dependencies you should see that the Visual Studio detects dependencies on MFC90.dll and MSVCR90.dll. You must add the corresponding Merge Modules for these DLLs.
5. From the Project menu, point to Add and click Merge Module. Select Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86.msm and Microsoft_VC90_MFC_x86.msm, and click OK. For the debug versions of these merge modules, select Microsoft_VC90_DebugCRT_x86.msm and Microsoft_VC90_DebugMFC_x86.msm.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can't see Project->Add->File or Right click on Project->Add-> File. The "File" option is not there!

Comment: It is indeed the best practice to use Merge Modules for deploying external dependencies when using Windows Installer.

Comment: @Aphelion: How to do it? I am new!

Comment: @System.Windows.Form sorry the link treats VS2005 and 2008, see the link for vs2010 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235285(v=vs.100).aspx